# How start and stop H2 server for testing

Tags: spring-mvc, testing, jdbc, junit4, h2

Done some REST API (Spring + Hibernate application), want to add some tests of controllers. Please help how start (@Before) and finish (@After) server? 
DataConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("file:${properties.home}app.properties")
public class DataConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        Resource config = new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(config);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(env.getProperty("HomeAutomation.entity.package"));
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("HomeAutomation.db.driver"));
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("HomeAutomation.db.url"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("HomeAutomation.db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("HomeAutomation.db.password"));
        return ds;
    }
}
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

app.properties:

```
HomeAutomation.entity.package = com.zzheads.HomeAutomation.model
HomeAutomation.db.driver = org.h2.Driver
HomeAutomation.db.url = jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/data/HomeAutomation
HomeAutomation.db.username = sa
HomeAutomation.db.password =
```

Application.java:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {    
    public static final String BASE_URL ="http://localhost:8080/";
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

And how test will looks like (need help here):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
public class RoomControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private RoomService roomService;
    @Autowired
    private EquipmentService equipmentService;
    @Autowired
    private ControlService controlService;

    private ApiClient client;
    private Gson gson;
    private static final String PORT = "4568";
    private static final String TEST_DATASOURCE = "jdbc:h2:mem:testing";

    @BeforeClass
    public static void startServer() {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void stopServer() {
    }

    @Before public void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @After public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test public void testAddRoom() throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("roomName", "Kitchen");
        values.put("squareFootage", "325");
        ApiResponse res = client.request("POST", "/room", gson.toJson(values));
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), res.getStatus());
    }
```

Comment: Just a quick remark to complete my answer below. If you wish to use the server mode, you should start a tcpserver but also use a tcp jdbc url, like ```jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/test```. You can also use the memory with tcp server. If you do not need the tcp server, you need to close properly the memory database for its content to be purged.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `start()` and `stop()` from this class: `org.h2.server.TcpServer`

Comment: this solution doesnot work in case when the H2 server startup is auto managed by the environment or by spring etc.